# python: append dict into list issue

Tags: python

I'm actually new on python. With exam code, I found something strange

Here's my code.

```
cat_log = []
container = {}
for index in range(10) : 
    container["idx"] = index
    cat_log.append(container)
print(cat_log)
```

I want the result like this: [{'idx' : 0 } , { 'idx' : 1 } , { 'idx' : 2 } , { 'idx' : 3 }].
But my code doesn't output this result.
Something like this: [{ 'idx' : 3 } , { 'idx' : 3 } , { 'idx' : 3 } , { 'idx' : 3 }]
I've googled why this happens, but I didn't find any right idea.
What's wrong and why?

Comment: Well, sorry. That won't work. Dictionaries don't support multiple keys of the same value.

Comment: Sorry, I just posted wrong result.

Comment: `contain = container` doesn't make a new dict.

Comment: This isn't strange at all, this is how it always works in Python. Assignment **never implicitly copies** in Python. You should read [Ned Batchelder's Facts and Myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, despite the syntactic similarities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you append container you are not making a copy, so you are just appending a reference to the same dict over and over. You are mutating the dict as well and you cannot have multiple values of the same key in a dictionary, it is just overwriting idx with the current index each time.

Instead, append a new dictionary each iteration. Eg:

```
cat_log = []
for index in range(10) : 
    cat_log.append({"idx": index})
print(cat_log)
```